# Write bmp image into a directory using GD library

Tags: php, ubuntu, gd

- I'm using php GD library for reading and writing image (png, jpeg, bmp) in web service application. GD library is here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php
- The issue of GD library is that it doesn't support bmp type.

  - To read bmp image, I'm using the function imagecreatefrombmp() at https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/src/Helpers.php#L555
  - To write bmp image, I don't have any solution yet. So is there any suggestion for writing bmp image ? I hope the function will be like imagepng(), imagejpeg() or own source as imagecreatefrombmp() above.
- My platform: php 5.5.9, ubuntu 4.20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GD doesn't support saving to a BMP image. My recommendation would be first saving the manipulated BMP image to PNG format, and then use ImageMagick separately to save it back to BMP:

```
<?php    
$image = new Imagick('path/to/saved/image-from-bmp.png');
$image->writeImage('path/to/new/bmp/image.bmp');
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. imageMagick is likely to be suitable for my application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php image magician open source library.

PHP Image Magician is an open source project that uses PHP GD to perform image manipulation in an easy, succinct way. BMP support
Read and write.

https://github.com/Oberto/php-image-magician

http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com/

Comment: Image-magician is also a good library for image manipulation. Thanks.